# How to use Payum Stripe Checkout Button in our own template?

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments, payum

I just added the Payum Bundle to my e-commerce application so users will be able to pay online. However, I'm having a problem with Payum templates.

When the user chooses to pay using stripe, I redirect them to the prepareAction in the PaymentController as described by stripe documentation. The payment works fine. However, the user arrives first in a blank page only with the stripe button and then he sees the popup window to fill the payment information. What I wanted is that he arrives directly on this form without this blank page.

I am trying to find a way to override this template or include it in my template but I cannot figure out how to do. I think I must have been doing something wrong. It should be easier to integrate stripe from what I read. Could anybody help me?

Comment: This is not a valuable question to ask a group of people. This will involve working knowledge of your system and the ability to troubleshoot.

Comment: Try to change `payum.stripe_checkout.template.obtain_checkout_token` parameter in the container. 

It is default value defined here https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Factory/Gateway/StripeCheckoutGatewayFactory.php#L53

Comment: John, I don't understand why it is not a valuable question to ask a group of people. This is not the behavior of my application but the behavior of payum stripe checkout bundle and its prepareAction. I'm just asking how I could change the templates or include them in mine because it is not working. Thanks @MaksimKotlyar for the answer. That's what I was looking for ;)